# Align multiple plots with unequal labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have a series of line plots, made with ggplot2.

I want to arrange them in one plot, and I can do this with `plot_grid` from the cowplot package. However, because the labels (*Universität vs. SP*) are unequal in length, the plots are not aligned properly. What I want is that the grid area is perfectly aligned along all plots. Any idea how I can achieve this?

This is my code:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot_party, plot_educ, plot_sex, labels=c("A", "B", "C"), ncol = 1, nrow = 3)
```

[image: example]

Comment: by adding `align = "v"`?

Comment: oh wow, didn't think it was that easy. thanks a lot

Comment: @Jimbou can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `cowplot::plot_grid()` function you can specify the align parameter which controlls the alignment as follows:

- default ("none" )
- horizontally ("h")
- vertically ("v")
- align in both directions ("hv")

So you need to run:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot_party, plot_educ, plot_sex, 
                   labels = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                   ncol = 1, nrow = 3,
                   align = "v")
```